# Замена символов

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Можете мне помочь? У меня не получается. :( Задание: 
дана строка, заменить каждую из цифр, предшествующую первому вхождению символа "+", на "-".

То, что я пытался:

```
public class NewClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
    StringBuilder a= new StringBuilder();
String s="hsthshs+ tsh+th+ rsery";
String s0="-";
char b='+';
a.append(s);
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
if(a.charAt(i)==b){
a.insert(i, s0);
i+=s0.length();
}
}
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
System.out.println();    
}
}
```

Comment: Примите ответ, который вам наиболее понравился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно читаем задание: 
каждую из ЦИФР предшествующую ПЕРВОМУ вхождению символа "+" заменить на "-"

```
public static class NewClass
{
    public static void main(
        String[] args)
    {
        // Добавим цифр, чтобы было что заменять.
        String s = "abc123abc+0abc123+123";

        //Находим индекс первого фхождения символа "+".
        int p = s.indexOf("+");

        String result;
        if (p == -1) {
            //Если симвоол "+" не найден в строке, то результатом будет исходная   
            //строка
            result = s;
        } else {
            //Если символ "+" найден,
            //результат склеиваем из двух частей. 
            //Первая - до первого вхождения символа с заменёнными на "-" цифрами.
            //Вторая часть - после плюса и без изменений.
            result = s.substring(0, p).replaceAll("[0-9]", "-")
                + s.substring(p);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Для замены цифр на минус используется [регулярное выражение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: А у вас плюсик теряется. `s.substring(0, p+1)`

Comment: @Dex таки вы правы, спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Предложу свой вариант, навеянный реализацией [[@Andrey2517](/users/6738/andrey2517)](/users/6738/andrey2517), суть в том, что мы ищем наш плюс, а после того, как отыскали, возвращаемся назад попутно меняя цифры на минусы. Оставшаяся часть строки остается нетронутой.

```
public static String chMinus(String input) {//наша функция
    //объявим переменную, хранящую символ для замены
    final String ch = "-";
    //воспользуемся специальным классом для работы со строкой
    //данный класс в отличие от обычного String не имеет такого недостатка
    //как неизменность `immutable` (любые операции со String после первого      
    //присвоения создают новую строку, что часто плачевно сказывается на скорости)

    //в качестве параметра конструктора мы передаем нашу исходную строку
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(input);
    //найдем первый "+"
    int p = res.indexOf("+");
    //циклически будем двигаться назад, пока не дойдем до начала строки (p=0)
    while(p >= 0) {//если же "+" нету в строке, мы никогда не зайдем в этот цикл

        //проверяем, является ли текущий символ строки цифрой
        if(Character.isDigit(res.charAt(p))) {
            res.replace(p, p+1, ch);//если да, то заменяем на "-"
        }
        p--;//переходим к предыдущему символу
    }
    return res.toString();//возвращаем измененное значение нашей входной строки
}
```

Работает он несколько быстрее реализации от [[@Синицын Артём](/users/6925/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC)](/users/6925/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC) (время получено стандартной функцией `System.currentTimeMillis()`), для вот такой строки `String s = "a4a5a6a7a8a9a10a45345434+535345+";`

1. 100 запусков - 4 против 21
2. 100 000 запусков - 172 против 1142
3. 1 000 000 запусков - 1341 против 5913
4. 10 000 000 запусков - 13108 против 47649
5. 100 000 000 запусков - 133642 против 453708

Comment: Как вы думаете, @Dex, возможно ли решение с использованием только одного регулярного выражения? У меня такое составить не получилось из-за невозможности добавления квантификаторов в обратную проверку.

Comment: @Синицын Артём, я все это к тому, что всецело полагаться на регулярные выражения, при решении тривиальных задач, нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Решение Артема мне очень понравилось и все понятно. 2 вариант я вот не понял т.к с такими методами не знаком ( начал Java недавно).

Comment: @Andrey2517, его вариант проще в написании, а у себя сейчас добавлю комментарии.